# How to measure SVG elements in React?

Tags: reactjs, svg

To render certain SVG elements in my app, I need to first measure some other SVG elements.

For example, imagine a `<text>` element that is randomly positioned in a square (0,0) - (100,100), and can have various font sizes, font families, etc.

If the text is positioned at (10,20), and have a width of 30 and a height of 40, I'd like to set the containing `<svg>` width to 40 (= 10 + 30) and height to 60 (= 20 + 40).

The main point is: `<text>` needs to be measured **before** rendering the `<svg>`.

To help with `<text>` measurement, I created the following component:

```
class MeasureSvgElements extends React.Component {
  storeSvgReference = svg => {
    if (svg !== null) {
      this.svg = svg;
    }
  };

  measure() {
    const childElements = Array.from(this.svg.children);
    const dimensions = childElements
      .map(element => element.getBoundingClientRect())
      .map(({ width, height }) => ({ width, height }));

    this.props.onChange(dimensions);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.measure();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.measure();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg width="0" height="0" style={{ display: 'block' }} ref={this.storeSvgReference}>
        {this.props.children}
      </svg>
    );
  }
}
```

which can be used to measure multiple elements at once:

```
<MeasureSvgElements onChange={onChange}>
  {['Hello', 'Stack', 'Overflow'].map(str => <text>{str}</text>)}
</MeasureSvgElements>
```

`onChange` will be called once the dimensions are ready.

Now, I'm not sure what's the best way to use `<MeasureSvgElements>` to render the containing `<svg>` using the dimensions provided by `onChange`.

Or, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be to mock-up each `text` element prior to render, gather the heights and widths (in addition to positions), and then iterate through the dimensions to determine what sizes should be applied to the parent.

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-43880276-dynamic-svg-textbox-id3rt

## Data Structure:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const yourTextData = [
  {
    id: 0,
    posX: 0,
    posY: 0,
    str: "~~Hello~~",
    fontFamily: "URW Chancery L, cursive",
    fontSize: "30"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    posX: 20,
    posY: 20,
    str: "~~Stack~~",
    fontFamily: "URW Chancery L, cursive",
    fontSize: "30"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    posX: 40,
    posY: 40,
    str: "~~Overflow~~",
    fontFamily: "URW Chancery L, cursive",
    fontSize: "30"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    posX: 0,
    posY: 80,
    str: "This SVG with text sets its own",
    fontFamily: "Arial, sans-serif",
    fontSize: "30"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    posX: 40,
    posY: 120,
    str: "d i m e n s i o n s",
    fontFamily: "FreeMono, monospace",
    fontSize: "30"
  }
];
```

## Define your component and hooks:

```
const DynamicSVGText = (props) => {
  const [svgWidth, setSvgWidth] = useState(0);
  const [svgHeight, setSvgHeight] = useState(0);
  const [textDims, setTextDims] = useState([]); // array of objects, defining dims/pos for each texteach text
```

## Measure function

This will be called when creating each `text` element and saved to the `textDims` hook.

```
  const measure = (data) => {
    // create a mock element
    let newText = document.createElement("text");
    newText.setAttribute("id", data.id);
    document.body.appendChild(newText);

    // append text data
    let theTextEle = document.getElementById(`${data.id}`);
    theTextEle.innerHTML += data.str;

    // append text font / size, bc might as well be fancy
    theTextEle.style.fontFamily = data.fontFamily;
    theTextEle.style.fontSize = `${data.fontSize}px`;

    // measure element
    let width = theTextEle.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    let height = theTextEle.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    // delete element
    theTextEle.parentNode.removeChild(theTextEle);

    // set data
    let dimData = [width, height];
    //console.log(dimData);

    // return dimension data
    return dimData;
  };
```

## Function for creating `text` elements:

```
  const SvgText = ({ text }) =>
    text.map((data, i) => {
      let dimensions = measure(data);

      let updatedTextDims = textDims;

      updatedTextDims[data.id] = {
        x: data.posX,
        y: data.posY,
        w: dimensions[0],
        h: dimensions[1]
      };

      return (
        <StyledText
          fontFamily={data.fontFamily}
          fontSize={data.fontSize}
          key={data.id}
          x={data.posX.toString()}
          y={(data.posY + dimensions[1]).toString()}
        >
          {data.str}
        </StyledText>
      );
    });
```

## useEffect to detect when the `textDims` hook changes

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let tw = 0; // longest width
    let th = 0; // tallest height

    // loop through text elements and their dimensions,
    // set total width/height to the greatest dimensions across objects
    for (let d = 0; d < textDims.length; d++) {
      let thisWidth = textDims[d].x + textDims[d].w;
      let thisHeight = textDims[d].y + textDims[d].h;

      if (thisWidth > tw) {
        tw = thisWidth;
      }

      if (thisHeight > th) {
        th = thisHeight;
      }
    }

    setSvgWidth(tw);
    setSvgHeight(th);
  }, [textDims]);
```

## Finalize the component, and a bit of style

```
  return (
    <svg
      width={svgWidth.toString()}
      height={svgHeight.toString()}
      style={{ display: "block" }}
    >
      <SvgText text={props.text} />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <DynamicSVGText text={yourTextData} />
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const StyledText = styled.text``;
```